# VSCode SSH, connected and not connected at the same time

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

[VSC Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otWBA.png)

I'm tryint to connect to host (RPi4) over LAN. Netstat on RPi4 shows the connections as ESTABLISHED. Yet, I'm unable to open any folders and the "opening remote" goes on and on forever.

I'm able to connect via SSH, even from VSC terminal so it's not SSH or connection issue. I rebooted both machines and I even manually installed VSC Server on RPi4 matching client commit hash. Is there anything else I could do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Solved. Turns out the solution was hidden in the remote host SSH logs. The issue was a refused local port forward. solved by editing ssh_config and changing AllowTcpForwarding from "no" to "yes"